# jQuery: switch between states & classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[**JSFIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/d5q6p00L/)

I got `hidden-input` with `display: none` and `opacity: 0`. The animation happens as planned on `label` click.

However, I need it to function as toggle actually, so that it can also hide with the same animation if `checkbox` is unchecked.

I thought my commented code will work but if you uncomment it, the `input` is never shown at all.

How can I modify the JS/CSS in a way that CSS opacity animation happens both on show & hide and also toggles properly between `hidden` and `visible` states?

**EDIT:** having `display: none` in a hidden state is obligatory here.

Comment: `fadeToggle` does exactly what you want! It hides an element with an animation on the first call, shows it again on the second call..

Comment: @RicoOcepek using jQuery to animate what CSS can do... it requests animations frames and just outrightly outdated way of animating things that is used by newbies in frontend

Comment: @knitevision your CSS3 solution is not supported by about 25% of browsers! jQuery is still the way to go if you want a website which is working exactly the same on all major clients..

Comment: @RicoOcepek who said I care about 25% of browsers? =) and what exactly is unsupported..?

Comment: @knitevision I was just assuming this :) CSS3 transitions are not supported by IE versions before 10..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this working version: http://jsfiddle.net/n4Lep9jf/

There are two changes:

1) You are making the various CSS changes and setting the class to `active` before even checking whether it is already active. Therefore, the `if` statement in your code will always return true, thus removing those CSS changes. Instead, the class should be set to active (along with the accompanying lines of JS) in the `else` block of the if statement.

2) I set `$toggler` to refer to the checkbox itself, and changed the `click` handler to `change`. I found that the `click` event on the label was firing twice, and this solves that issue. I was surprised by the fact that the click handler was firing twice, but my guess is that's standard for behavior for labels that are linked to checkboxes.

Comment: That is close to what I wanted. I added a set timeout for the animation to play and then hide it. It works. http://jsfiddle.net/n4Lep9jf/1/.